# Lowering chances of unnatural death to the minimum with technology

Tags: science-based, biology

[Orwell High](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oppression) is a dangerous place, school shootings happen at least once in a week. 
However, ***nobody has died*** yet, despite the fact that by now, the building almost entirely consists of planes that were driven into it.

And this seems odd. How can I reinforce the fragile, unnecessary complex body of you, organics, to be as hard-to-destroy as mine?!

Ok, that's maybe too broad. Let's put it in this way:

**How can I preserve an organic being's brain and cells in a prolonged, suspended state as quickly as possible, without being able to tamper with the environment around them?**

- It should be able to preserve the human brain, regardless of the environment.

Comment: It's really unclear what you are asking. Your headline seems to ask about reducing the changes of death with technology. For clarification, we would want to know what technological era we are in, and what kind of resources per person might be available. Your bold text asks how we can preserve brain and cells in a suspended state (suspended animation?), as quickly as possible, without being able to tamper with the environment around them. Those seem like different questions, but that last part is what really throws me. How can we do ANYTHING ever without modifying the environment?

Comment: Each paragraph seems to belong in an entirely different universe from the rest of the text. Frankly this is the Mother of All Unclear Questions. Kindly do everybody a favour, including yourself, and think it through clearly and simply in a way that communicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Arthur C. Clark level technology (i.e. "Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic), then you can just make up a technology which does what you want.  There's load of complications to deal with (such as the gee-forces against your organs in what are known as "internal collisions" as they hit your skull and ribcage), but nothing magic wont solve.

To solve it further, you really need to scope what sorts of dangerous events happen.  Shootings are one thing.  Planes hitting it is another.  Nuclear ordinance dropped on it would be different.  We've spent a *lot* of time as the human race developing ways to damage the organic stuff that makes up the bodies of our "enemies," so I'd expect an arms race if you had such a technology.  As we developed new ways to keep people alive, surely new ways to kill them would surface.  I'd build my technology off of this back and forth game of cat and mouse.  Invent a few defensive technologies using today's tech, then try to attack them with more advanced weapons.  Then build technologies to stop those attacks.  So on and so forth

To start this process off with today's tech level, I'll link an excerpt from the [Discovery Channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L_Gp7zSJQQw) on the topic.  Their device is my recommendation.  That and some good body armor.  Or, if you prefer something already marketed, the [Invisible Bike Helmet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RfBPmv2Qb-Q) is a good place to start.

Comment: Ok, then I make the fluff like: *"We've spent all of our budget on super helmets and brain preserving techniques, this is why we still use Zyklon B as a pesticide."*

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to preserve the brain when you could just store the data?

In [Altered Carbon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altered_Carbon) by Richard K. Morgan, people have a small chip in their spine that is a backup of the brain. Should someone get killed, they just upload them into a new body. For the rich, they also augment this with daily offsite backups